Why was my question closed for lack of context?
I asked a probability question on the math site
Formula for Probability of rolling higher
The question was closed, saying I needed more context. I clarified a bit more, thinking that would be enough, but it still wasn't re-opened. i mean, i could give more context, but i feel like listing everything about the game would be irrelevant noise in the post.
It seems to me that the question is just like all the other dice game questions on the site, and imo its readable and well organized. I don't understand why my question was closed and downvoted. Why was it closed?

This should be asked on [meta.math.se]
